# Is using express necessary to create rest API in Google Cloud Function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am new at Google Cloud function. My understanding is you can actually create a restful API using Google Cloud function without using express. But I am seeing implementations of Restful API's using express and Google Cloud Functions.

What is the difference and is it required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Cloud Functions is a serverless solution, if you use express inside of them you are actually creating an app server within an app server.

So the best recommendation does not call it inside a function, you can check Google Documentation about it but basically, you can take advantage of just creating the functions and use the export method inside your JS files, when you deploy them GCP will create automatically each function for yours.

Left you an example below, Cloud Functions will manage the req,res for you as express would do it. So you just focus in handling the logic.

[image]